# How to change activeindex in TabMenu

Tags: primefaces

I have a question concerning the component Tabmenu of primefacess and specifically the attribute active index, the index of the page selected. I would like to change it according to the page chosen but it is always fixed on the front page! This is my code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:tabMenu rendered="true"   widgetVar="index">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench" oncomplete="index.select(1)"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search" oncomplete="index.select(2)"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document" oncomplete="index.select(3)"/>  
    </p:tabMenu> 
    </ui:composition>
```

it doesn't work

---

thx for your cooepration ,but its not working

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:tabMenu activeIndex="0" > 
    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"  update="@all"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench" update="@all" />  
    <p:menuitem value="Composants" url="/pagess/pagesComposant/Composant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-search" update="@all"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Dossier d'equivalence" url="DEQ.jsf" icon="ui-icon-document"  update="@all"/>  
</p:tabMenu> 

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. When are you trying to change the tab index? When the user clicks on what page? Clicking on the tabs should activate that tab automatically. You don't have to do anything. If you want to change the active tab while clicking (or doing) something else you have to explain what that "something else" is.

Comment: That's it who disturbs me because in the site primefaces the tabmenu example change automatically without any bean but for me he does not synchronize with menu item that I have seleced                      what is the problem , is that because for a template???

Comment: What browser (and which version) are you using? Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: no ,there is no errror ..but i don't known why when i chose a menuitem  it return me the page but with not chanching the activeindex

Comment: it not work on chrome and explorer

Comment: I guess you will need to add some more code to your question. It is hard to follow or to find out what you are trying to do. For example: How do you know the index is not changed? Where and how do you show the index. And: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: OK at the site primefaces example TabMenu is active page dindice 0 "overview" and when I choose another page eg Demos page index changes the menuitem "Demos" is pressed .. for my application  every pages change but it with not pressed index it allwys on the first index

Comment: have you tried putting update="@all" in each of the menuitems?

Answer (score 1):

The *activeIndex* attribute on tabmenu sets the tab on that index active. If you click around the tabs at the primefaces tabmenu showcase and keep looking at the source examples, you'll see that this is exactly what is happening. They set different activeIndex on each page.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution in the PrimeFaces showcase. You can add a request parameter to the menuitem and append this parameter to your url. So no backing bean is needed to keep the active index:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
   <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" url="page1.xhtml?i=0">
      <f:param name="i" value="0" />
   </p:menuitem>
   <p:menuitem value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" url="page2.xhtml?i=1">
      <f:param name="i" value="1" />
   </p:menuitem>
   ...
</p:tabMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{activeIndex}">
        <p:menuitem 
            value="tab1"
            url="/tab1.jsf">
        </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem 
            value="tab2" 
            url="/tab2.jsf">
        </p:menuitem>   
    </p:tabMenu>

    <h:panelGroup id="mainPanel" style="width:100%">
        <ui:insert name="page">Page Content</ui:insert>
    </h:panelGroup>

</ui:composition>
```

**Set Parameter in tab pages**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="activeIndex" value="1" />

    <ui:define name="page">
        tab1 content
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have two .jsf files namely **Menu.jsf** and **Fabricant.jsf**

Put following snippet code in **Menu.jsf** that will select 0th Index from menuItem

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="0" > 
    <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
    <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"/>  
</p:tabMenu>
```

Put following snippet code in **Fabricant.jsf** that will select 1st Index from menuItem

```
   <p:tabMenu activeIndex="1" > 
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="Menu.jsf" icon="ui-icon-star"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" url="/pagess/pagesFabricant/Fabricant.jsf" icon="ui-icon-wrench"/>  
    </p:tabMenu>
```

For more information [click here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenu.jsf)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:tabMenu rendered="true"   widgetVar="#{bean.index}">  
        <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{bean.redirect(1)}"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Fabricants" action="#{baen.redirect(2)}"/>  
</p:tabMenu> 


on my bean {
int index;
getter and setter;

public String redirect(int a){
if (a==1){
  index=1;
return "Home" or // "/home.jsf
 }
else if (a==2){
 index =2;
return "Fabricant";
}
}
```

it works fine thx all for your cooperation :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the tab menu as a component that other pages `<ui:include>`ed.  I used the suggestions above for the following fix:

The component (let's call it myMenu.xhtml):

```
<p:tabMenu id="myMenuBar" activeIndex="#{parentIndex}">
    <p:menuitem value="Page One" action="#{PageOneBacker.mainNavigation}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Page Two" action="#{PageTwoBacker.mainNavigation}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Page Three" action="#{PageThreeBacker.mainNavigation}" />
</p:tabMenu>
```

Now in each page, I have:

```
<ui:include src="../myMenu.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="parentIndex" value="XXX" />
</ui:include>
```

Where XXX is the numeric index of that page in the menu, starting from 0.  I'm not 100% happy having to "hard-code" these index'es like this, but it is a solution.