# Changing ActiveIndex in TabMenu

Tags: primefaces, tabs

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and have run into an issue with changing the ActiveIndex. ActiveIndex doesn't change when going between tabs.  This is my TabMenu code:

```
 <h:form id="formMenu">
 <p:tabMenu id="tabMenu" activeIndex="#{toolbarBean.currentTab}">
      <p:menuitem value="Main"  action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(0)}" />
      <p:menuitem value="Page2" action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(1)}" />
      <p:menuitem value="Page3" actionListener="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(2)}" />
      <p:menuitem value="Page4" action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(3)}" />
  </p:tabMenu>
  </form>
```

toolbarBean.java

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class toolbarBean implements Serializable {

private int currentTab;

public int getCurrentTab() {
    return currentTab;
}

public void setCurrentTab(int currentTab) {
    this.currentTab = currentTab;
}

public String changeActiveIndex(int currentTab) {
    this.currentTab = currentTab;
    switch (currentTab) {
    case 0:
        return "/main";
    case 1:
        return "/page2";
    case 2:
        return "/page3";
    case 3:
        return "/page4";
    default:
        return "/page5";
    }
}
```

}

The action part works properly where the variable currentTab gets assigned the right value.  However, once it is running the page redirect part, toolbarBean is being reset and activeIndex starts off at 0 again.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So, what do you want to do?

Comment: I would like it to change the active index of the tab so the current page's tab is seen as active to the user.

Comment: Why don't you use just like in the Showcase? Put the page link in the "url" property of p:menuitem, instead of control it in your bean. Take a look: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabMenuSupport.jsf

Comment: Note that the **actionListener** on Page 3 Tab won't generate navigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change activeindex in TabMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013132/how-to-change-activeindex-in-tabmenu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my answer in this question:

[How to change activeindex in TabMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013132/how-to-change-activeindex-in-tabmenu/24780062#24780062)

I think it's what you are looking for.

**Edit:**
Here is the complete answer:

I have found a solution in the PrimeFaces showcase. You can add a request parameter to the menuitem and append this parameter to your url. So no backing bean is needed to keep the active index:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
   <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" url="page1.xhtml?i=0">
      <f:param name="i" value="0" />
   </p:menuitem>
   <p:menuitem value="Search" icon="ui-icon-search" url="page2.xhtml?i=1">
      <f:param name="i" value="1" />
   </p:menuitem>
   ...
</p:tabMenu>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit lazy ;-)

Comment: Why is your solution better @ErkanErol?

Comment: @QueryLars Because you have to send the index in  all refreshes and redirects in your method. It is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I've unsuccessfully tried to reproduce the error.

I believe that the code sample I used has the features you need. Check it out:

**The View*

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">  
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
        <h:form id="formMenu">
            <p:tabMenu id="tabMenu" activeIndex="#{toolbarBean.currentTab}">
                <p:menuitem value="Main"  action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(0)}" />
                <p:menuitem value="Page2" action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(1)}" />
                <p:menuitem value="Page3" action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(2)}" />
                <p:menuitem value="Page4" action="#{toolbarBean.changeActiveIndex(3)}" />
            </p:tabMenu>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
        <h:outputText value="South unit content." />  
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">  
        <h:outputText value="West unit content." />  
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">  
        <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />  
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
        MAIN
    </p:layoutUnit>  
</p:layout>
```

**The Managed Bean**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ToolbarBean implements Serializable {

    private int currentTab;

    public int getCurrentTab() {
        return currentTab;
    }

    public void setCurrentTab(int currentTab) {
        this.currentTab = currentTab;
    }

    public String changeActiveIndex(int currentTab) {
        this.currentTab = currentTab;
        switch (currentTab) {
            case 0:
                return "main";
            case 1:
                return "page2";
            case 2:
                return "page3";
            case 3:
                return "page4";
            default:
                return "page5";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the ToolbarBean is almost the same. As you are using @Named, see if the ManagedBean is indeed in session scope.

Another thing worth mentioning is that main.xhml, page1.xhtml, page2.xhtml and etc, has the same content except for the center layout unit content.