# Primeface 8: Nested Tabview, Dynamic tabview inside a fixed one

Tags: primefaces, tabview

I have a requirement where I display a list when you go to a fixed tabview. The list will keep changing beased on the selection of a datatable row.
I have two questions.

1. How can I display the inside tab when the first time the fixed tab is clicked?
2. If I select one datatable row,
   a)I get the fixed tabview.
   b)If I select one of the tabs in Fixed tabView, I get the dynamic tabView .
   c) I go to a tab in the dynamic tabView(say 2nd tab)
   Now if I select any other row and perform a->b, I get the dynamic tabView with the 2nd tab open.How can I reset this dynamic tabView to always open the first tab when the fixed tab is selected.
   I am attaching the image of my page below[image: Tabviews]

Comment: I could do this by using activeIndex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing ActiveIndex in TabMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961972/changing-activeindex-in-tabmenu)